# How to know when a user is holding an UI button?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It's pretty easy to detect a button OnClick event, however I can't figure out how to detect when a using started and stopped touching a button. How can this be done?

This is what I'm trying right now:

```
public class Touching : MonoBehaviour {
    public static bool mouseDown;
    public float timeMouseDown;

    void Update(){
        if (mouseDown) {
            timeMouseDown += 1;
            Debug.Log ("meditar");
        }
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData){
        Debug.Log ("OnPointerDown");
        mouseDown = true;
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData){
        Debug.Log ("OnPointerUp");
        mouseDown = false;
        timeMouseDown = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need 3 variables: a `boolean` (which you already have), a `DateTime` (the moment the user clicked the button) and a `TimeSpan` (the click duration).

```
boolean mouseDown;
DateTime startTime;
TimeSpan clickDuration;

public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData){
    Debug.Log ("OnPointerDown");
    mouseDown = true;
    startTime = DateTime.Now;
}

public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData){
    Debug.Log ("OnPointerUp");
    mouseDown = false;
    clickDuration = DateTime.Now - startTime;
}
```

As Huacanacha suggests, it would probably be faster to use Unity's specific `Time` functions instead of generic `DateTime` and `TimeSpan`. You could try both, and measure the impact on performance.

Comment: `DateTime` and `TimeSpan` are unnecessarily heavyweight here and they don't directly relate to game time (think Time.timeScale != 1, think needing to relate button press/release times to game events). Better to simply use `float startTime` and `float endTime` setting them with `Time.time` in the corresponding events. Delta time is of course `endTime-StartTime`.

Answer (score -1):

You could start a thread on mousedown then tell the thread to stop at mouseup. This would keep the form responsive.
It would look something like this:

```
using System.threading
class my class
{

private thread thread0(functiontoloop);

mousedownevent
{
    thread0.start();
}

private void funtiontoloop()
{
    do something here
}


mouseupevent 
{
     thread0.Abort();
//  or u could use
 thread0.suspend();  // that way you could resume if needed

}
}
```

and use it:

```
using System.Threading;
Thread t;
private void btn_Xmas_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
        ThreadStart del=new ThreadStart(dothis);
       t=new Thread(del);
    t.Start();
}

private void btn_Xmas_MouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    t.Abort();
}
public void dothis()
{
    while(true)
    {
              this.x=this.x+10;     
                                                               this.crimsonModel.writeStringToAll("newX:"+x.ToString());
        }
}
```